# Ngrx: How to prevent data loss after state update in array of elements?

Tags: state, angular7, ngrx

My Angular application shows a list of `Item` where every `Item` (Component) has its own state composed by the following properties:

```
{
    name: 'item name',
    status: 'OK'
}
```

I used a ngrx store to mantain an updated state for every component (the OK state is coming from a backend-service via Effect, so I retrieve data asynchronously to be put into the store).

Angular polls a backend-service and if the status field for the n-th item is not OK, the UI has to be colored differently.

The back-end service returns an array of items of the type shown above and it is placed into the `list` below.

So, here's the State representation:

```
export interface State {
    list: Item[]
}
```

Now I would like to store one more information in every Item of the list upon an event: the `open` property which is not depending by the backend. It is set via UI upon a button click.

So I would have a state like this at a certain point:

```
[{
    name: 'item 1',
    status: 'OK',
    open: true
},
{
    name: 'item 2',
    status: 'OK',
    open: false
},
{
    name: 'item 3',
    status: 'OK'
}
...
{
    name: 'item n',
    status: null
}]
```

The `open` property is set by a UI event. Other properties come from the backend (via array).

My problem is that every time I dispatch an action that pulls data from the back-end service, all the elements are overwritten (I clearly understand why) and I have this:

```
[{
    name: 'item 1',
    status: 'OK'
},
{
    name: 'item 2',
    status: 'OK'
},
{
    name: 'item 3',
    status: 'OK'
}
...
{
    name: 'item n',
    status: null
}]
```

What's the best approach to solve this?
I think it could be easily solved into the reducer, but I still can't figure out how.

I tried to:

- use a different store
- use another array in the same store

but I think I will have synch issues in both cases

- I tried to change the reducer from this:

```
case ItemsActions.STORE_ITEM_LIST:
    return {
    ...state,
    list: action.payload
}
```

to this (update each item specifying each field):

```
case ItemsActions.STORE_ITEM_LIST:
return {
    ...state,
    list: action.payload.map((item, index) => {
        action.payload[index].name === item.name ? {
            ...item,
            name: item.name,
            status: item.status
        } : item
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory you have to map over the payload and "join" the current state value with the incoming value.

This translates into the following implementation:

```
case ItemsActions.STORE_ITEM_LIST:
return {
    ...state,
    list: action.payload.map((item) => ({
            ...state.list.find(item2 => item2.name === item.name) || {}, // if the item isn't found just create an empty object
            name: item.name,
            status: item.status

    }))
}
```

To make these updates easier you can take a look at:

- [@ngrx/entity](https://ngrx.io/guide/entity)
- Immer - [Clean NgRx reducers using Immer](https://blog.angularindepth.com/clean-ngrx-reducers-using-immer-7fe4a0d43508)

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting an error on `...state`. It says _Declaration or statement expected_. It's like the syntax is not correct. For the moment I would like to try to update without using @ngrx/entity or Immer.

Comment: Yep true, I updated the syntax. You have to wrap the object with `()`

Comment: Thank you very much @timdeschryver I solved with your help, making just small adjustments to my code.